# Display name of column using foreign key with distinct

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am doing a movie booking project in which i want to display movies with their cinema and time slots available from this code i want to get cinema name with distinct

```
def movies(request, id):
    cin = shows.objects.filter(movie_id=id).values_list('cinema_id',flat=True).distinct()
    print(cin)
    #cin = shows.objects.filter(movie_id=id)
    movies = movie.objects.filter(movie_id=id)
    show = shows.objects.filter(movie_id=id)
    context = {
        'movies':movies[0],
        'show':show,
        'cin':cin,
    }
    return render(request, "movies.html", context )
```

**Here's my model.py with Pk,Fk keys set**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here

class cinema(models.Model):
    cinema_id=models.AutoField(primary_key='true')
    role=models.CharField(max_length=30,default='cinema_manager')
    cinema_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phoneno=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cinema_name

class movie(models.Model):
    movie_id=models.AutoField(primary_key='true')
    movie_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    movie_des=models.TextField()
    movie_rating=models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    movie_poster=models.ImageField(upload_to='movies/poster', default="movies/poster/not.jpg")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.movie_name

class shows(models.Model):
    show_id=models.AutoField(primary_key='true')
    cinema_id=models.ForeignKey('cinema',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie_id=models.ForeignKey('movie',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    seat=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cinema_id.cinema_name +" | "+ self.movie_id.movie_name +" | "+ self.time
```

**Sample DATABASE accounts_shows**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FupK5.png)

Comment: before reading your whole code, i noticed you wrote `'true'` and its `True` without quotations and the the first letter is capitalized.

Comment: @Moha369: it will probably not matter however, since it is more Pythonic to check the truthiness, but I definitely agree that one should use `True` :)

Comment: and why context is `movies[0]` ? @WillemVanOnsem we should check every thing not correct before answering a question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the `Cinema`s that have a `shows` with `movie_id` the given movie with:

```
cinema.objects.filter(shows__movie_id_id=movie_id).distinct()
```

You probably want to use `.get(..)` here by the way to obtain the `movie` instead of `.filter(..)` so:

```
movie = movie.objects.get(movie_id=id)
```

That being said, there are still some problems with your models:

1. you use <s>`primary_key='true'`</s> instead of `primary_key=True`;
2. according to [**PEP-8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the names of classes are written in `CamelCase`, so `Cinema` instead of <s>`cinema`</s>, etc.
3. model names are *singular*, so `Show` instead of <s>`Shows`</s>;
4. the `ForeignKey`s are *not* suffixed with an `_id`, since Django will automatically construct a "twin field" with an `_id` suffix, so it is `movie = models.ForeignKey(..)`, *not* `movie_id = models.ForeignKey(..)`.

After making the above changes, you can query the cinema's with:

```
Cinema.objects.filter(show__movie_id=movie_id).distinct()
```